# What are the costs to establish an LLC and to maintain it?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, accounting, limited-liability-company, income-tax

**What's the average (approximately) cost to open a basic LLC in Florida state or in NY state?** (FYI in my case is to buy an house in Miami and rent it. I already have a bank account in the U.S.)

**What's the average cost to maintain it?** I mean accounting + bookeeping + tax filing costs, etc.

Side questions:

1. If I come to Florida or NY state., where do I generally have to go to open/maintain an LLC? Here
   in Italy we usually ask a CPA (Certified Public Accountant) /
   tax advisors. Where do I look for them? On the web? What do I need to
   look for: "CPAs" or "Tax Advisors" or "Lawyers"?
2. How much paper work do I have to do every year to keep my LLC
   running? Do people in US usually do this on
   their own, or do they go to places like lawyers or CPAs to manage
   the LLC book-keeping/accounting/tax-filing and all the paperwork.

   (**I
   would like to be sure I do not make errors. I don't want to end up
   in jail just because I forgot to pay taxes or added nondeductible costs to the economic income.**)

   For instance: I have a small company in Italy and every 3 months I
   have to bring cost/revenues invoices to the CPA. The CPA registers them
   and at the end of the year he does the tax filing. So basically he
   takes care of all the paper work/accounting/tax-filing, etc.

Comment: First look for a "lawyer" and ask "do I need a LLC?". LLC (like most of the business entities in the US) are registered and maintained on State level. As I said, there are 50 of those. You should probably ask about Florida, not "US".

Comment: @littleadv: I updated the question as you suggested. Anyway I struggle to believe the accounting/book-keeping/tax-advisor cost of an LLC could vary so greatley among US states. I'm not talking about taxes here, but about accounting cost, I suppose I will need someone to keep the booking like the revenues invoices and the cost invoices. In case they audit the LLC, I suppose I can't tell the auditor I have no invoices cause I throw them into the trash bin at the end of the day.

Comment: last year I paid my CPA $550. This year it would be double, I guess. I do my own books, but the complexity of the returns varies depending on what goes in each year. There were years I did my returns myself, because these years were simple enough, and then the CPA costs were $70 (the cost of TurboTax at store).

Comment: @littleadv: $550, is a puny amount of money, here in Italy we are used to pay to CPAs 2000€/year just for a small pathetic one person company. An LLC in Italy costs not less than 5000€/year just for the CPA.

Comment: It is likely that what you call LLC in Italy is in fact a Corporation in the US, not what we call LLC here.

Comment: To make this less localized, how about framing the question as "What Are the Costs..."?  that will give you an idea of how to shop and make the best decision based on price and quality.

Comment: @littleadv: no, what I call LLC is exactly a Limited Liability, whic is called SRL in Italy and it costs about 4000 € / year just for the CPA. What you call a Corp. here in Italy is called SPA and that costs loads of money just to keep it open.

Comment: @Marco, according to the wikipedia (I know, not the best reference, but my Italian is rather rusty), you're wrong. Both SRL and SPA can be recognized as corporations per the US law. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_liability_company#Italy

Comment: @littleadv LLC is limited liability company and is in no way a partnership

Comment: @Neuromancer in no way? I wouldn't be so categorical if I were you. LLC is taxed as a partnership (unless its SMLLC and then it is taxed as individual). From legal protection standpoint, there's no difference between LLC and LLP. Similarly, assets distribution, loss/gain attributions - are all the same as in partnerships. The only difference between LLC and LLP is that LLC can be single-member.

Comment: @littleadv: I don't see where wikipedia says that SRL can be recognized as corporation in US. SRL in Italy is the exact equivalent to LLC in US or LTD in UK, except it's laden by accounting costs and taxes. :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The cost will be around $300-$500 if you do it correctly it in Florida and can be over a $1,000 if you do it in New York (New York is more expensive due to a publication requirement that New York has for LLC’s). 
   The price ranges I’ve given include filing, state fees, getting a tax ID number (EIN), operating agreement, membership certificates, registered agent fees and publication fees if done in New York.

   Each state also have licensing boards and city fees that are applicable, so you would want to also make sure that you are keeping compliant there.
2. Yearly paperwork to keep the LLC running won’t be so expensive, expect the state to charge a yearly fee and require some basic information to be submitted.  I had a quick look at Florida, and with someone filing it for you, expect around $200 to $250 a year, plus registered agent fees.  If you are late in Florida the penalty is $400 so you definitely would want a service that provides compliance calendar notifications to make sure you are on time with fees.

   In regards to bookkeeping and taxes, yearly tax filing will start at $250 to $500 for an LLC and move up from there depending on the services being offered and the amount of time of work.  I recently referred someone to an accountant that will charge $250 to file an almost zero tax return on an LLC.  I think $40 an hour is a little low for a bookkeeper but it all depends on where you are.  I know in some major cities bookkeepers expect $75 an hour or higher. So the expectation in Miami and Manhattan will probably be more expensive than Jacksonville and Albany. If you doing a little business don’t expect the cost to be too much on the bookkeeping.

   So, breakdown:

   $300-$500 (FL) - $1,000 (NY) Registration of LLC + any business license, city or other registrations

   $250 Yearly Fee + Yearly Registered Agent + any business licenses, city or other fee

   $500 Tax Return + Bookkeeping Fee

   Banks will charge more than a personal account so expect $120 a year plus.

   In regards to service I would look at companies that specialize in foreigners setting up  businesses in the US, because they will have services designed to help you more than services that primarily specialize with US clients. You are going to have some different needs, based on not having a Social Security Number or establishing from overseas.

Comment: Hi and welcome! I removed your link seeds and please do disclose your affiliation next time for the sake of fairness. Other than that its an informative answer. It would help even more if you'd provide the references for the numbers, as they may change and it is helpful to know where to find the up-to-date information.

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer in general terms, since I'm not familiar with the price ranges in Florida.

The LLC formation costs $125 (state fee). In addition you'll need a registered agent. Registered agent could be your CPA/EA/bookkeeper/property manager/local friend, or you can pay firms specializing in providing registration and agents services such as [NorthWestern](http://www.northwestregisteredagent.com/florida-LLC.html) or [LegalZoom](http://www.legalzoom.com/limited-liability-company/limited-liability-company-packages.html) (there are many others). You'll need to pay an annual fee of ~$140 in Florida. If you are using someone to do the formation, they'll charge more (usually the on-line services are cheaper than a local CPA or attorney, by $100-$300).

Bookkeeping will probably be charged by the hour, but some bookkeepers charge flat fees for small accounts. Per hour would be probably in the range of $40-$80.

You'll have to pay taxes - both in Florida (where the property is) and on the Federal level to the IRS. You'll be paying them as a non-Resident **individual**. Your CPA/EA will charge you anywhere between $150 to $500 for that (if they charge more - run away, unless there's some specific complication that requires extra costs). You will need a ITIN for that, your CPA/EA can help you get one or you can apply yourself.

Be careful with all those people selling cr@p about organizing in Delaware/Wyoming/Nevada (like CQM in his answer). Organizing in a state other than where the properties are located (or off-shore) won't save you a dime, and not only that - it will **add** to the costs. Because you'll have to pay to the state where you organized (CQM mentioned Wyoming - $50/year), keep registered agent in the state of organization (+$99) and **also** do all the things I've described above about Florida - as a "Foreign" (out of state) entity, which may mean higher fees. It won't save you any taxes as well, because you pay taxes to the state from which you derive income, which is Florida, either way.

Remember that what you call LLC in Italy may be in fact a "Corporation" as defined in the US, and there's a huge difference. You should probably not put a real-estate property in a Corporation in the US.

You **must** get a legal advice from a (Florida) lawyer ($0-$500/hr consultation), and a tax advice from a (Florida) CPA/EA ($0-$200/hr consultation). Do not consider anything I write here as a legal or tax advice, because it is not. You need a professional to help you because as an Italian, you don't know how things work exactly and relying on rumours and half-truths that you may find and get over the Internet may end up costing you significantly in damages. Also, talk to a **reliable** real estate agent and property manager before making any purchases.

Comment: Costs to open LLC is US are puny compared to the ones in Italy. It's cool!!!

Comment: @Marco LLC in the US is a partnership, the "C" is rather misleading. I believe partnerships are much cheaper in EU than corporations.