# What is the average cost of a LLC tax return and what it entails? (FL)

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, florida

I want to understand the cost associated with complying with yearly maintenance of a Florida LLC.

[This answer outlines some of the costs, but does not specify what is required](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/27697/1635)

Comment: The subject line is not the same as the content of your question. Which is it that you're asking about? The question you quoted answers to what your question is in the body, so are you only interested in information about the tax return?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the LLC is organized.  If you have partners, and the LLC is small, then figure about $600-$700 to do the taxes.  If you are the only partner, then about $100 to do the additional work as a schedule C.  Keep in mind the partnership makeup can change as you desire.